# Как вывести в консоль цветное сообщение ? java

Tags: java

Хочу вывести в консоль цветную надпись "Привет", жёлтым цветом, как это сделать ? Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека ?

Comment: Посмотрите [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println). Там дается ответ на Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(ANSI_YELLOW + "Привет" + ANSI_RESET);
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EH5pRRs

Comment: @NastyStuffy см. комментарий Анастасии под вашим вопросом.

Comment: такой способ не работает